# Does using format() allow sql server to use that column for selecting the right index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I was looking at an execution plan and saw a message that said something along the lines of conversion may affect cardinality estimates. I did some further research and saw that the use of functions can affect the ability for SQL Server to estimate cardinality because that column becomes effectively invisible. See [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1308427-391-1.aspx).  There was a column in a query that was being converted to from a small date time to a varchar and then being casted back to a date.  It looks like the original dev was trying to supply the same column twice, once as a full date time, and once as a short date. `CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ELI.DDC1Date, 101) AS DATETIME) AS ShortDDC1Date`  Anyways, I updated the column in the select to `FORMAT(eli.ddc1date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as ShortDDC1Date` and went and reviewed the execution plan again.  The warning about conversion affecting cardinality estimates had disappeared.  Is the format function an exception to the affects it has on ability for SQL Sever to use indexes?  If so, why?

```
SELECT ELI.EInvoiceLineItemID
    ,ELI.EInvoiceID
    ,ELI.VendorID
    ,ELI.ServicerID
    ,ELI.CategoryID
    ,ELI.SubcategoryID
    ,ELI.ItemDate
    ,ELI.ItemQuantity
    ,ELI.ItemPrice
    ,ELI.AmountBilledToDate
    ,ELI.LifeofLoanTotalAllowable
    ,ELI.InvoiceTotalAllowable
    ,ELI.UnitAllowable
    ,ELI.GuidelineTypeID
    ,ELI.DDC1Date
    ,ELIP.CheckRequestID
    ,ELIP.PaymentTransactionID
    ,ELIP.NIPaymentTransactionID
    ,ELIP.NIPaymentDate
    ,ELIP.ACH
    ,ELIP.PaidDate
    ,ELIP.PaymentError
    ,ELIP.PaymentErrorDetail
    ,ELI.Adjusted
    ,ELI.Utility
    ,ELI.AdjustedAmount
    ,ELI.ExportedFilename
    ,ELIP.DisbursementAmount
    ,ELIP.CorporateAdvanceAmount
    ,ELIP.TransCode
    ,ELIP.CawPayeeCode
    ,ELIP.ReasonCode
    ,ELIP.SeqCode
    ,ELI.BatchCode
    ,ELIP.ProcCode
    ,ELI.UserComment
    ,ELI.BreakdownFromDate
    ,ELI.BreakdownToDate
    ,ELI.BreakdownBaseAmount
    ,ELI.BreakdownInterestAmount
    ,ELI.BreakdownPenaltyAmount
    ,ELI.BreakdownAdvanceDate
    ,ELI.ImageAttachment
    ,ELI.LineItemBreakdown
    ,ELI.CommentRequired
    ,ELI.ImageRequired
    ,ELI.ExceptionFlag
    ,ELI.DateCreated
    ,ELI.DateUpdated
    ,ELI.RequiredImagesAttached
    ,ELI.AmountBilledToDateOnOrder
    ,ELI.OrderTotalAllowable
    ,ELIP.PhaseCode
    ,ELI.DataServicerOrderID
    ,ELI.ServiceFromDate
    ,ELI.ServiceToDate
    ,ELI.CawPayeeCodeManualOverride
    ,ELI.OTAAmount
    ,ELI.PreviouslyBilledDate
    ,ELI.PreviouslyPaidDate
    ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ELI.DDC1Date, 101) AS DATETIME) AS ShortDDC1Date
    ,S.ServicerCode
    ,M.RegionCode
    ,ELIP.SplitTypeID
FROM [dbo].EInvoiceLineItem ELI WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN dbo.EInvoiceLineItemPayment ELIP WITH (NOLOCK) ON ELI.EInvoiceLineItemID = ELIP.EInvoiceLineItemID
INNER JOIN EInvoice E WITH (NOLOCK) ON ELI.EInvoiceID = E.EInvoiceID
INNER JOIN MasterLoanData M WITH (NOLOCK) ON E.MasterLoanDataID = M.MasterLoanDataID
INNER JOIN [dbo].Servicer S WITH (NOLOCK) ON ELI.ServicerID = S.ServicerID
WHERE ELIP.CheckRequestID > 0
```

Comment: Please show your entire query

Comment: Added the query

Answer (score 2):

I would be really, really surprised if `format()` did have that effect in general. The issue is that the second argument can be an expression -- you don't even have to have the same format on each row.

Even without that consideration, `format()` can change the ordering of the column, so the index couldn't be used for `order by`.

I should also add that [Aaron Bertrand is wary](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) of the performance of `format()`.

Comment: Upvote for the comment about the performance issues of the FORMAT function.

Comment: I also upvoted because this is useful information but I'm leaving the question open because it doesn't quite answer the question directly, nor does it provide a solution to the issue of supplying the same column in different formats in a way that can avoid issues with cardinality estimates (which may not be possible).